# swift storyboard translation does not work

Tags: swift2, ios9

a the moment, i translate my app from german to english language.
i have a main.storyboard (all in german language) and a sub file "Main.Strings" for the english language.

if i start my app on simulator with german language, all text will be shown in german. if i start my app in english language, some text will be shown in english - but not all.

i compare the object id with the object id of the textfield in the storyboard - no difference. but why will this textfield show not the english language ?

Comment: Is there anything in common amongst the objects that show in German instead of English?

Comment: i see, that only text in scroll views will not be translated. all labels are ok

Comment: What's "text is scroll views"? Do you mean UITextView objects? So this would seem to suggest that UITextView object text is not localizable in this way, would it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are expecting UITextView text to be localizable in the nib. It isn't.

Comment: that mean i have the uitextviews translate with: NSLocalizedString("XXX",comment:"") in a separate translate file?

Comment: I think so. I think you'll have to populate them all with code. (And, exactly as you say, localize that code.)